# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 Express support shared data sources in reporting services?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Does anyone know if SQL server 2008 R2 Express edition  supports shared data sources or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of researching, I have realized that SQL Express 2008 R2 supports shared data sources!